# WCF have exception pass to the client

Tags: wcf, exception

I have a service that may throw exceptions. I want to be able to catch the exceptions at the client. The main Exceptions I am interested in are `DbUpdateException` and `InvalidOperationException`. For the rest of the exceptions it is enough to know that an exception has been throws.

How can I have exceptions caught in the client?

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, this article also has good info on converting Exceptions/FaultExceptions - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649840.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your WCF service throws an exception, then by default it will come to the client as a `FaultException`. You can configure your service to include exception details in faults, like so:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

But *you probably don't want to do this*, it's never a good idea to expose internal implementation details to clients.

If you want to distinguish between different service faults, you can create your own class, and register this as a fault that your service will throw. You can do this at the service contract level:

```
public interface YourServiceContract
{
   [FaultContract(typeof(YourFaultClass))]
   [OperationContract(...)]
   YourServiceResponseClass YourServiceOperation(YourServiceRequestClass request);
}
```

The class you use for your fault contract doesn't have to implement anything (as you would have to do for a custom `Exception`), it will just get wrapped in a generic `FaultContract` object. You can then catch this in the client code like this:

```
try
{
   // service operation
}
catch (FaultException<YourFaultClass> customFault)
{
   ...
}
catch (FaultException generalFault)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Define a FaultContract so any clients can listen for that and include only the exception details you want to expose publicly.

Read this for more info: [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx)