# How to get the excpetion thrown in WCF server

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm developing a WCF server with `wsHttpBinding` and `SecurityMode as Transport` with a `CertificateValidationMode as Custom`, here is my custom `CertificateValidation` class:

```
public class CustomValidation : X509CertificateValidator
{
    public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        if (store.Certificates.Contains(certificate))
        {
            store.Close();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
           store.Close();
           throw new Exception("TEST TEST");
       }
    }
}
```

My client app:

```
try
{
   var client = new HelloWorld.HelloWorldClient();

   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, error) => true;

   client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
              StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
              StoreName.My,
              X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
              "server.com");

   Console.WriteLine("IP: " + client.GetIp());
   Console.WriteLine("Certificate: " + client.GetCertificate());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is that if the `Validate` method fails, it throws an exception, but in the client I get another exception saying that

> The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

How can I get the 'TEST TEST' message in the client?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you need to wrap the validate code inside it's on try{}cathc{}

Comment: Looks like this may have already been answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077140/wcf-have-exception-pass-to-the-client